# depth image based rendering

Tags: rendering

I have to implement a depth image base rendering. Given a 2D image and a depth map, the algorithm will generate a virtual view - what the scene would look like if a camera was placed in a different position. I wrote this function, V is the matrix with the pixel of 2d view, D the pixels from depth map and camera shift a parameter.
Z=1.1-D./255; is a normalization. I try to follow this instruction:
For each pixel in the depth map, compute the disparity that results from the depth, For each pixel in the source 2D image, find a new location for it in the virtual view: old location + disparity of that specific pixel.
The function doesnt work very well, what's wrong?

```
function[virtualView]=renderViews(V,D,camerashift)
Z=1.1-D./255;
[M,N]=size(Z);
for m=1:M
for n=1:N
d=camerashift/Z(m,n);
shift=round(abs(d));
V2(m,n)=V(m+shift,n);
end
end
imshow(V2)
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you want to do. If you wish to recompute a 2D image from a depth buffer and a RGB image from a different 3D point of view, it seems to me that you should be looking for a technique called relief mapping. People on this forum will unlikely be able to debug your code.